# Page working in FF, not in IE, where to start

Tags: html, css, dom

I have a page which is largely created by DOM script, which generates a table of images (normal img elements) from several webcams (helping out a friend with a pet boarding and my HTML/DOM is a bit rusty).

It works fine in FF3 or Chrome, but not in IE7,  In fact, the whole table is not visible in IE (but the body background-color is applied).

Looking at the page in IE, there are no script errors, the CSS appears to be applied OK, and the DOM appears to show all the cells and rows in the table, which are all generated.

Using the IE Developer Toolbar, running the Image report even shows the images (even though they don't appear in the table and there is no evidence of the table in the page as rendered - even the text in the cells isn't rendered)

In looking at the img elements and using the trace style feature, at one time, I saw that the img elements all had display : none, and it said inline style, but there's nothing in my code or stylesheet which does this.  That problem appears to have gone away as I started to add explicit entries for every table element in my stylesheet.

Where to start?

```
body { background-color : gray ; color : white ; margin : 0 ; font-family : Verdana, "lucida console", arial, sans-serif ; }
#CameraPreviewParent { text-align : center ; width : 100% ; }
#CameraTable { text-align : center ; width : 100% ; }
#CameraLiveParent { text-align : center ; margin : 50px ; }
#CameraLiveHeading { color : white ; }
td.CameraCell { text-align : center ; }
img.CameraImage { border : none ; }
a:link, a:visited, a:active, a:hover { text-decoration : none ; color : inherit ; }
table#CameraTable { color : white ; background-color : gray ; }
td.CameraCell { color : white ; background-color : gray ; }
```

Removing the stylesheet completely has no effect.

Here's the code of the page after generation (I apologize for the formatting from the DOM toolbar - I've tried to put in some linefeeds to make it easier to read):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML Strict//EN"><META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
<SCRIPT src="cameras.js" type="text/javascript"> </SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
function CallOnLoad() {
document.title = PreviewPageTitle ;         BuildPreview(document.getElementById("CameraPreviewParent")) ;
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<!-- Any HTML can go here to modify page content/layout -->
<DIV id="CameraPreviewParent">
<TABLE id="CameraTable" class="CameraTable">
<TR id="CameraRow0" class="CameraRow">
<TD id="CameraCell0" class="CameraCell"><A id="CameraNameLink0" href="http://192.168.4.3:801" class="CameraNameLink">Luxury Suite 1 (1)</A><BR /><A id="CameraLink0" href="camlive.html?camIndex=0" class="CameraLink"><IMG id="CameraImage0" title="Click For Live Video from Luxury Suite 1 (1)" height="0" alt="Click For Live Video from Luxury Suite 1 (1)" src="http://192.168.4.3:801/IMAGE.JPG" width="0" class="CameraImage" /></A></TD>
<TD id="CameraCell1" class="CameraCell"><A id="CameraNameLink1" href="http://192.168.4.3:802" class="CameraNameLink">Luxury Suite 2 (2)</A><BR /><A id="CameraLink1" href="camlive.html?camIndex=1" class="CameraLink"><IMG id="CameraImage1" title="Click For Live Video from Luxury Suite 2 (2)" height="0" alt="Click For Live Video from Luxury Suite 2 (2)" src="http://192.168.4.3:802/IMAGE.JPG" width="0" class="CameraImage" /></A></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</DIV><!-- This element is used to hold the preview -->
<!-- Any HTML can go here to modify page content/layout -->
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Apparently the DOM code which inserts with width and height of the images is not working right in IE:

```
var PhotoWidth = 320 ;
var PhotoHeight = 240 ;

var image = document.createElement("img") ;
image.setAttribute("id", "CameraImage" + camIndex) ;
image.setAttribute("class", "CameraImage") ;
image.setAttribute("src", thisCam.ImageURL()) ;
image.setAttribute("width", PhotoWidth) ;
image.setAttribute("height", PhotoHeight) ;
image.setAttribute("alt", thisCam.PreviewAction()) ;
image.setAttribute("title", thisCam.PreviewAction()) ;
link.appendChild(image) ;
```

**The response about the require TBODY element when dynamically building tables appears to be the entire problem - this appears to even set the image width and height to 0 in the DOM!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One gotcha I found is that in IE, if you dynamically create tables using `document.createElement()`, you need `table(tbody(tr(tds)))`. Without a `tbody`, the table will not show.

Comment: Awesome, who would have thought it would have such a weird effect.

Comment: one would argue putting tbody in there should be a requirement, firefox "fudges" them in if you'll look at firebugs interpretation of the page.

Answer (score 1):

The gotcha that always gets me is IE's mishandling of the `<script>` tag when it's used like `<script src="..." />` instead of an opening and then a closing `</script>` tag. I seem to run into that a lot because I tend to use XSLT to generate HTML output.

The first step, though, would be to post somewhere an example of a page that doesn't display properly. It doesn't have to contain any real data, just enough to show the problem. Nobody is going to be able to guess what the problem is without a working example.

Comment: Yeah, I discovered that earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Have you started by resetting the CSS to a common base?  Have a look at [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [YUI Reset CSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/).  (But without an example page to look at, we're going to be guessing what the actual problem is.)

Answer (score 0):

[Explorer Exposed! on positioniseverything.net](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer.html) lists bugs found only in IE.